# RxSwift Subject not firing event when called

Tags: swift, rx-swift, coordinator-pattern, publishsubject

I have an app using `MVP` with the `Coordinator` pattern.

When a child coordinator sends and event, I would expect my `AppCoordinator` to recursively call a method that selects the next coordinator based on some `SessionState`.

The basic flow of the app is as follows -

`AppCoordinator`

1. `start()` invokes `coordinateToRoot` with an initial state
2. Subscribes to `showStartScene()` which starts the child coordinator

`StartCoordinator`

1. `start()` creates `MVP` module which is now visible to the user
2. `MVP` module invokes `AuthSvc` which makes async call to iDP and confirms auth state
3. On completion of this task, publishes an event which is picked up by the subscription in the `AppCoordinator`'s `coordinateToRoot` method and the cycle repeats using the appropriate coordinator for the view state.

The issue however is that on the publish of that event, nothing is happening. `start()` is not showing it received the event and `coordinateToRoot` is not called again.

I have created the most basic version I can below to demonstrate this. I have also hardcoded `showStartScene` to return `.signedIn` rather than a look up of the auth state.

In the below example, I would expect once the view is loaded, `presenter.signal` should immediately emit an event that causes a print statement to show.

**SessionState**

```swift
enum SessionState: String {
    case unknown, signedIn, signedOut
}
```

**AppCoordinator**

```swift
final class AppCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void> {

    private let window: UIWindow

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
    }

    override func start() -> Observable<Void> {
        coordinateToRoot(basedOn: .unknown)
        return .never()
    }

    /// Recursive method that will restart a child coordinator after completion.
    /// Based on:
    /// https://github.com/uptechteam/Coordinator-MVVM-Rx-Example/issues/3
    private func coordinateToRoot(basedOn state: SessionState) {

        switch state {
        case .unknown:
            return showStartScene()
                .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] state in
                    self.window.rootViewController = nil
                    self.coordinateToRoot(basedOn: state)
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        case .signedIn:
            print("I am signed in")

        case .signedOut:
            print("I am signed out")
        }
    }

    private func showStartScene() -> Observable<SessionState> {
        let coordinator = StartCoordinator(window: window)
        return coordinate(to: coordinator).map { return .signedIn }
    }
}
```

**StartCoordinator**

```swift
final class StartCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void> {

    private(set) var window: UIWindow

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
    }

    override func start() -> Observable<CoordinationResult> {

        let viewController = StartViewController()
        let presenter = StartPresenter(view: viewController)

        viewController.configurePresenter(as: presenter)

        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return presenter.signal
    }
}
```

**Start MVP Module**

```swift
protocol StartViewInterface: class {
    func configurePresenter(as presenter: StartPresentation)
}

protocol StartPresentation: class {
    var viewIsReady: PublishSubject<Void> { get }
    var signal: PublishSubject<Void> { get }
}
// MARK:- StartPresenter
final class StartPresenter {

    // Input
    let viewIsReady = PublishSubject<Void>()

    // Output
    let signal = PublishSubject<Void>()

    weak private var view: StartViewInterface?

    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(view: StartViewInterface?) {
        self.view = view

        viewIsReady.bind(to: signal).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

}

extension StartPresenter: StartPresentation { }

// MARK:- StartViewController
final class StartViewController: UIViewController {

    private var presenter: StartPresentation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let presenter = presenter {
            presenter.viewIsReady.onNext(())
        }

    }
}

extension StartViewController: StartViewInterface {
    func configurePresenter(as presenter: StartPresentation) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }
}
```

Interestingly if I do something like this in `StartCoordinator` the process does work, it has however not what I am trying to achieve.

```swift
    override func start() -> Observable<CoordinationResult> {

        let viewController = StartViewController()
        let presenter = StartPresenter(view: viewController)

        viewController.configurePresenter(as: presenter)

        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()


        let subject = PublishSubject<Void>()


        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            subject.onNext(())
        }

        return subject
    }
```

For reference my `BaseCoordinator` looks like -

```swift
/// Base abstract coordinator generic over the return type of the `start` method.
class BaseCoordinator<ResultType>: CoordinatorType {

    /// Typealias which allows to access a ResultType of the Coordainator by `CoordinatorName.CoordinationResult`.
    typealias CoordinationResult = ResultType

    /// Utility `DisposeBag` used by the subclasses.
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    /// Unique identifier.
    internal let identifier = UUID()

    /// 1. Stores coordinator in a dictionary of child coordinators.
     /// 2. Calls method `start()` on that coordinator.
     /// 3. On the `onNext:` of returning observable of method `start()` removes coordinator from the dictionary.
     ///
     /// - Parameter coordinator: Coordinator to start.
     /// - Returns: Result of `start()` method.
     func coordinate<T: CoordinatorType, U>(to coordinator: T) -> Observable<U> where U == T.CoordinationResult {
         store(coordinator: coordinator)
         return coordinator.start()
             .do(onNext: { [weak self] _ in self?.free(coordinator: coordinator) })
     }

     /// Starts job of the coordinator.
     ///
     /// - Returns: Result of coordinator job.
     func start() -> Observable<ResultType> {
         fatalError(message: "Start method should be implemented.")
     }

    /// Dictionary of the child coordinators. Every child coordinator should be added
    /// to that dictionary in order to keep it in memory.
    /// Key is an `identifier` of the child coordinator and value is the coordinator itself.
    /// Value type is `Any` because Swift doesn't allow to store generic types in the array.
    private(set) var childCoordinators: [UUID: Any] = [:]

    /// Stores coordinator to the `childCoordinators` dictionary.
    ///
    /// - Parameter coordinator: Child coordinator to store.
    private func store<T: CoordinatorType>(coordinator: T) {
        childCoordinators[coordinator.identifier] = coordinator
    }

    /// Release coordinator from the `childCoordinators` dictionary.
    ///
    /// - Parameter coordinator: Coordinator to release.
    private func free<T: CoordinatorType>(coordinator: T) {
        childCoordinators[coordinator.identifier] = nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I added some `debug` operators and I can see the order appears off for the next event and the subscription

```
2019-11-08 10:26:19.289: StartPresenter -> subscribed
2019-11-08 10:26:19.340: StartPresenter -> Event next(())
2019-11-08 10:26:19.350: coordinateToRoot -> subscribed
```

Why is `coordinateToRoot` subscribing after `StartPresenter` is created?

Comment: I believe `coordinateToRoot` subscribes *after* start is called on the child coordinator due to the `coordinate` method on your `BaseCoordinator` class. The subscription takes place after the view has been setup.

Answer (score 0):

`coordinateToRoot` is not connected to the lifecycle of the Observable returned by `AppCoordinator.start(_:)`. This means that there is no guarantee to the order in which `coordinateToRoot` and `StartPresenter` are subscribed to.

To guarantee the order, I think you can use the `do` operator and pass a closure for the `onSubscribe` argument. This `onSubscribe` closure will run before the subscribing to the underlying observable.

Here is the change I think you could make:

```swift
final class AppCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void> {

    override func start() -> Observable<Void> {
        return Observable<Void>.never().do(onSubscribe: { [weak self] _ in
             self?.coordinateToRoot(basedOn: .unknown)
        })
    }
}
```